# Uso della virgola con la congiunzione "però"

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

Ho la tendenza a scrivere la congiunzione "però" fra virgole in frasi come, per esempio, questa:

> Mi domando, però, quale sia l'origine di quest'espressione.

Tuttavia, non sono sicura che quest'uso della virgola sia corretto. Ho l'impressione che sia un'influenza della mia lingua (il catalano). Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Comment: Grazie alla tua domanda mi sono chiarito anch'io un dubbio, +1

Comment: Ho un dubbio che spero possa risolvermi: ritiene corretto usare un però dopo un punto? Grazie per un gentile riscontro. Aldo Gierardini

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Aldo! Per favore, usa "Your Answer" per scrivere una risposta alla domanda. Per porre una domanda, devi usare "Ask question" che trovi nell'angolo in alto a destra della pagina. Potresti riscrivere la tua domanda là?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Direi che non abbia niente che non vada, anche se l'italiano tollera anche una relativa scarsità di virgole: io probabilmente scriverei «Mi domando però quale sia l'origine di quest'espressione».

A favore dell'uso tra virgole, cito dal solito Serianni un passo di Pirandello: «Non esce mai di casa, però, la sua figliuola!», *Così è (se vi pare)*, V 27. (A scanso di equivoci: la battuta compare in una conversazione in cui qualcuno ipotizza che la figlia della signora Frola faccia certe cose, e qualcun altro, rivolgendosi direttamente alla signora, osserva che così non può essere perché la ragazza non esce mai di casa.)
[Qui](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/p/pirandello/cosi_e_se_vi_pare_1918/html/testo.htm) si può trovare il testo della pièce pirandelliana.

Per l'uso senza virgole, ecco un esempio da Natalia Ginzburg: «La casa di via Pastrengo era molto grande [...]; era però molto buia», *Lessico famigliare*, 31.

Comment: Si può anche usare una sola virgola dopo la parola *però*? Ho trovato alcuni esempi. «Io vorrei sapere però, quando mai s'è visto un personaggio che, uscendo dalla sua parte, si sia messo a perorarla così come fa lei, e a proporla, a spiegarla.» (Luigi Pirandello, *Sei personaggi in cerca d'autore*). «Verso l'alba però, la Principessa ebbe occasione di farsi il segno della croce.» (Giuseppe Tomasi di Lampedusa, *Il Gattopardo*).

Comment: Nell'uso moderno questi due casi di virgole singole hanno un aspetto strano. Qui, più che il “però”, c'entra il fatto che in altri tempi si sarebbero forse messe quelle virgole anche nelle stesse identiche frasi senza la congiunzione, mentre oggi ometteremmo la virgola (soprattutto nella prima). (Poi va' a sapere quanto non sia dovuto a redattori e tipografi...)

Answer (score 4):

Le virgole intorno a "però" si possono sia mettere, sia non mettere. A mio avviso, vi è solo una lieve differenza tra le due possibilità.

- Se le virgole ci sono, come ha già osservato bobie, c'è una maggiore enfasi sul "però", e dunque sul fatto che la frase è contrapposta ad un'altra affermazione precedente.
- Se le virgole non ci sono, viene a mancare questa enfasi, dunque quello che viene esaltato è il significato della frase, piuttosto che la sua opposizione alla precedente.

A riguardo della frase in esame, nel primo caso io intendo che la persona che parla esprime un certo dubbio sul fatto che esista una spiegazione ragionevole all'origine dell'espressione di cui si discute (e, quindi, potrebbe anche mettere in discussione la liceità stessa dell'espressione, in un'interpretazione un po' esagerata). Nel secondo caso esprime piuttosto la curiosità di sapere l'origine dell'espressione.

Chiaramente si tratta comunque di una differenza piuttosto lieve.

Answer (score 3):

Dopo la congiunzione 'però' la virgola non ci vuole
 "non vorrai *negare però che* sia un gran lavoratore", "aspettami a casa, *se però non* sarò arrivato per le sei, esci pure"

Il tuo esempio nella forma normale sarebbe: " la frase l'ho capita...., però mi domando quale...", inverrtendo l'ordine la punteggiatura non cambia: ", *mi domando però* quale...".

Le virgole sono possibili quando si aggiunge una *precisazione* o correzione a quanto già detto: "...è quasi la stessa cosa, con questa sola *differenza, però, che* ...", *non sono però obbligatorie*: "... sono molto debole, non tanto però da non poter camminare".

Infine, qualunque parola può essere messa tra virgole per varie ragioni, non ultima quella stilistica, in quanto suggeriscono una pausa e aggiungono enfasi.

Ricapitolando: la tua frase sempra proprio una precisazione, quindi le virgole ci possono stare, anche se non sono obbligatorie come in catalano. In ogni caso le puoi sempre mettere con la motivazione che vuoi dare un po' d'enfasi

A proposito della frase citata da DaG, si può ricordare che forse è un uso particolare: in genere all’inizio o alla fine di una frase *'però,'* viene seguito da una virgola e viene pronunciato con tono interiettivo, come un'esclamazione per esprimere (finta) sorpresa o altro sentimento, per constatare una realtà apparentemente insospettata o contraria all’apparenza: "però, quella ragazza non è poi così male!"

Questa non è una interpretazione obbligata (ho detto: 'forse'), giustificata,però, dalla presenza di una virgola e dal punto esclamativo:"lui non esce molto, però, sua figlia quanto *(non)* esce (poverina)!

*nota: positivo o negativo, a chiunque si riferisce, non cambia il valore interiettivo, come già detto, è una interpretazione possibile che è servita *solo* a introdurre un nuovo concetto.

Comment: Grazie del tuo intervento, bobie, ma non ho capito bene un paio di punti. Primo: secondo te sarebbe corretta la punteggiatura del periodo «La frase l'ho capita, mi domando però quale sia l'origine di quest'espressione»? Quella povera virgola mi sembra che faccia un superlavoro; io metterei un punto o un punto e virgola.

Comment: Secondo: non mi sembra che nella citazione pirandelliana il “però” sia nel senso in cui è usato in una frase come «però, quella ragazza non è poi così male!». [Qui](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/p/pirandello/cosi_e_se_vi_pare_1918/html/testo.htm) si può trovare tutto il testo del dramma: contro l'ipotesi che la figlia vada a trovare la madre, qualcuno sta eccependo che invece così non è, appunto perché non esce mai di casa.

Comment: bobie, scusa, non ho spiegato bene il contesto della frase di Pirandello sulla figliuola. Il soggetto di “non esce” è sempre la figlia: riformulando, stanno dicendo: «Però la sua figliuola non esce mai di casa!»

Comment: Cioè, non c'è nessun “lui”: si parla *solo* della figliola (e “sua” si riferisce all'interlocutrice, la signora Frola). Non è una contrapposizione tra due persone. Qualcun altro ipotizza che la figliola faccia certe cose, e qualcuno fa notare che non può essere perché non esce mai.

Comment: bobie, la tua non è un'“interpretazione”: hai preso la stessa frase di Pirandello e le stai facendo dire una cosa diversa. Tanto valeva inventare una frase ex novo.